# Task switching while editing a comment causes the iOS app to lose comment and stop responding

Tags: bug, ios-app, ipad

I opened a comment from my inbox, started writing a reply, and switched to another app and back.

The comment is lost, the app is back in my inbox, and clicking on items in my inbox does nothing.

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

This happens on iPad but not iPhone.

Comment: No repro here. What version? (you should post bug reports from the app so it auto appends app version etc).

Comment: Thanks @Cai. Haha it just happened to me while looking up the version. Yes, I'm posting from the app. Was happening with the previous version. I remembered there was an update, updated to 1.6.1, still happens. Will try rebooting the device now.

Comment: If you go to "about" from the sidebar there is a "Submit a bug report" button which you should use for bugs, it auto appends device and app version info to the post

Comment: Added info that the bug report feature appends. Still happening after reboot.

Comment: Confirmed it does not happen on iPhone.

Comment: I think this happens when the app swaps out - I can get away with briefly switching to another app but if I do anything intensive like browse to a Web page then it gets lost. My iPad is much older than my iPhone so I bet it has less RAM.